# batch export emails in a conversation as text files

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to export all the emails in a finished conversation and save them as text files in my drive. Now I have to search the emails and save them as text file one by one.

But I need to do that for different conversations every week. Is there any way to quickly find all the emails in a conversation and auto save them all as text files?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find all messages in a conversation, you can use an Outlook Search Folder. Just create a new Custom Search Folder and specify the Criteria on the Advanced tab: Field -> All Mail Fields -> Conversation, Condition = is (exactly), Value = your conversation's initial subject (without all Re:, Fw:, etc. prefixes).

Now you have the search folder containing all messages from the conversation. In order to export all these messages, you can select them all and use the free [Export Messages to Text Files](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesExportTXT/) utility to save all selected messages to text files. I recommend this tool because I'm one of the developers.